# If statement test fails when comparing numbers read from file

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a file with the following input (Sample not full file)

```
JANE,SMITH,12,1000298,2
CLARA,OSWALD,10,10890298,4
```

We have `FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Grade`, `ID`, and `School`. I have a loop that reads each into their own variable. The last number `(2,4)` indicates what school they belong to and I have the code that changes the `2` to `HS`, and `4` to `ML`. I need to have the test pass. Where if it finds `2` do this find a `3` do this and so on.

```
#!bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read  First_Name Last_Name Grade Student_Id school
do 


 if [[ $school == 2 ]]
    then
        School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/2/HS/g')
    elif [[ $school == 3 ]]
     then
        School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/3/MI/g')
      else
       School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/4/ML/g')
   fi
   echo $First_Name $Last_Name $Grade $Student_Id $School
done < $1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Ok. So school has 2,4 as per the input from the file. When it finds a 2 it should change that 2 to HS. But the test fails. Even if I use `-eq` it fails. I add `""` just to see if it did anything, but nothing. When I echo `$school` it gives me the right numbers 2,4 but It fails to compare it. 
Correct output

```
JANE,SMITH 12 1000298 HS
CLARA OSWALD 10 10890298 ML
```

What I get is

```
CLARA OSWALD 10 10890298 ML
```

As it skips straight to the else part. It does not check the first one. And if I try to check for `$school == 4` or (`-eq`) it will just fail that too.

Comment: Dear John Doe, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Very nice question and well explained what the problem is. Keep up the good work and the Doctor Who references! Also have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/, which will already help you out a lot.

Comment: Furthermore, it looks like your shebang is wrong. Try to write `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (you were missing a slash in the beginning of your first line). When I fix this, it works for me.

Comment: I bet your data file has DOS-style CRNL line endings, so $school is actually `2\r` and you won't be able to detect that with the naked eye. Run `dos2unix` on both the data file and the script file, and ensure your text editor saves files with unix line endings.

Comment: Also, depending on how you execute the script, it will run in a separate process, so you don't need to backup and restore the IFS value.

Comment: `if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]` should be used when comparing 2 integers. For more information about bash comparison operators please see: [Link](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: Also, staments like `if [[ $school == 2 ]]; then  School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/2/HS/g'); ...` can be changed by `if [[ "$school" == 2 ]]; then School="HS";`

Comment: And obviously, since you already use `sed`, you could just do: `sed -e 's/2$/HS/;s/3$/MI/;s/4$/ML/;s/,/ /g' inputfile`

Comment: @kvantour, in bash, arguments to `[[` are *not* subject to word splitting, so technically quotes are not required in `[[ ... ]]`. They certainly don't hurt though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**inputfile**

```
JANE,SMITH,12,1000298,2
CLARA,OSWALD,10,10890298,4
DONALD,DUCK,10,10890298,3
DAISY,DUCK,10,10890298,2
```

**script**

```
IFS=","                          # set field separator
while read line; do              # read all line
   set -- $line                  # split lines
   case $5 in                    # depending on last value in line
      2) school="HS";;           # choose the school form
      3) school="MI";;
      4) school="ML";;
   esac
   echo "$1,$2 $3 $4 $school"    # print output
done < inputfile                 # read from inputfile
```

**output**

```
JANE,SMITH 12 1000298 HS
CLARA,OSWALD 10 10890298 ML
DONALD,DUCK 10 10890298 MI
DAISY,DUCK 10 10890298 HS
```

Comment: You'll want to do `set -f` to turn off filename expansion for the unquoted `set -- $line` -- if one of the fields is `*` you don't want to substitute  a list of filenames.

Comment: But if we allow ourselves to be restricted to bash, `while IFS=, read -ra fields` bypasses the filename expansion risk.

Comment: What you have does works. It looks like @glenn jackman might be right. If i use your code with the file I have it erases the last number and only prints JANE,SMITH 12 1000298. But if i use your inputfile it works. But I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: I provided the answer in my comment. Read `man dos2unix` and tell me what you learned.

Comment: @glennjackman I honestly do not understand the dos2unix. Mac does not have it on its man page. And when I looked it up it still made no sense to me. I  ended up using tr -d '\r' < inputfile > outputfile

Comment: You gave no indication of your OS and I assumed Linux. Did removing the carriage returns help?